# Returns elements disableds the form - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using function `getPost()` in data request.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

The `$data` variable not contain value the elements marked with disabled.

```
<select data-id="1" class="form-control selecao-pergunta" name="perguntas[64]" disabled="disabled">
```

It is possible return all elements and values the form in Zend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for disabled form elements are not posted back to the server, so there is no way to access them with PHP (or any server side language). This is part of the HTML standard.